# using cin and cout in textmate

Tags: c++, textmate

I am usually a Java programmer, and have used textmate for that almost exclusively, but lately I started using C++ with it. but when i use even the most basic programs and incorporate the *cin* keyword, and run the program, I dont get an oppurtunity to put in anything during runtime and sometimes it inserts random values by itself! for example, if i ran this in textmate:

```
#include <iostream>

int stonetolb(int);

int main() {

    using namespace std;
    int stone;
    cout << "enter the weight in stone";
    cin >> stone;
    int pounds = stonetolb(stone);
    cout << stone << "stone = ";
    cout << pounds <<" pounds.";
    return 0;
}

int stonetolb(int sts) {

        return 14 * sts;
}
```

I would come out with the output:

> enter the weight in stone32767stone = 458738 pounds.

Why is this happening, and how do I stop it?

Comment: Ehm user error ... are you missing new lines? I believe the program is executing your instructions perfectly. Exactly which part of the output is random?

Comment: i did not input any value whatsoever and it inserted 32767 where i would have put in any value i wanted

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the input statement `cin >> stone` is failing, and stone has an undefined value. You need to check for input failure by using `if (cin >> stone) { ... } else { // input failure }`. As for why such a simple program would exhibit failing behaviour, I don't know- you would have to check the textmate documentation.

Comment: Testing the above code on OS X (which we know the OP was using because he mentions Textmate), I can confirm that this is exactly what is happening -- uninitialised, 'stone' has a value if 32767, and if the user enters a non-numeric answer to the initial prompt, then reading in from the stream fails, and stone keeps its initial value.  The way to stop this from happening is to actually insert a value when the program asks for one (and preferably, to check for and handle the error condition when reading from the stream)